# datepicker or popup element is hide in iframe

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, popup

How to resize iframe when popup or calendar or dynamic element with position absolute is open in iframe?

When datepicker is at `bottom` of page in `iframe` then it hide the calendar elements.

[image]

It also happen when popup(colorbox) is open in iframe and I Click on reset button which will open Enter `"Email Address textbox"`. After opening textbox it hide the content below the `Email Address textbox`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put max height size of Iframe, or put scroll option.

As I see there you are using asp.MVC (mvc datetime picker) if I'm right remove your I frame functionality and load your View, Partial view as in here:

[Render a partial view inside a Jquery modal popup on top of a parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923305/render-a-partial-view-inside-a-jquery-modal-popup-on-top-of-a-parent-view)

Comment: I can't put scroll option. this is the reason i am resizing the iframe according to content but i am getting problem with popups. And i cannot remove iframe because my application is used as widget in 3rd party or other websites and my widget is build upon jquery which will conflict with 3rd party script. so i have used the iframe.