# Controller cannot go to server Side in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am doing my application in MVC. I have registration and Login links. I have implemented Login link in all pages. If  i click login it is moving to the server side(controller) and opening. MY problem is from whatever page i click login it needs to open in the same window in popup. It means that it doesn't go the server side.

My code is

```
@model SYTMain.Models.Login
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_for_login.cshtml";

    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_for_login_registration .cshtml";
}

<center><h2>Login</h2></center>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Login">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.");
        <div style=" margin-bottom: 400px;">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Login</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.EmailID)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.EmailID)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.EmailID)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
                </div>
                @*<div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.RememberMe)
                    </div>*@
                <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Layout

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    @*<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />*@
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Popup/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/Popup/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js"></script>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                show: {
                    effect: "shake",
                    duration: 100
                },
                hide: {
                    effect: "explode",
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

</head>
<body style="    margin: 0px auto;overflow: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; /* width: 1330px; */height: auto;">

    <div class="layoutouter">
        <div class="layoutlogo">
            @Html.ActionLink("Sell Your Time", "Index", "Home")

        </div>


        <div class="layoutmenu">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["EmailID"])))
            {

                @Html.ActionLink("Signout", "Logout", "CU")
            }
            else
            {
                @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Create", "CU")

            }
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        @*<strong>Welcome @Session["EmailID"]</strong>*@

        <div>
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:1000px ; margin:0px auto;">

        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <div class="layoutfooter">
        <div class="layoutfooter_data">
            <div class="layout_location">
                @Html.ActionLink("Change Location", "yy", "zz")
                <span>|</span>
            </div>
            <div class="layout_feedback">
                @Html.ActionLink("Feedback", "yy", "zz")
                <span>|</span>
            </div>

            <div class="layout_help">
                @Html.ActionLink("Help", "yy", "zz")
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="footer_copy">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - acutesoftsys</p>
        </div>


        <div class="footer_condition">
            <div class="footer_term">
                <span>|</span>
                @Html.ActionLink("Term & Condition", "", "")

            </div>
            <div class="footer_policy">
                @Html.ActionLink("Privacy Policy", "yy", "zz")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

My controller code is

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Login(Login loginDetails)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (SYTEntities context = new SYTEntities())
                {
                    var LoginUser = context.tblUsers.Where(a => a.EmailID == loginDetails.EmailID && a.Password == loginDetails.Password).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (LoginUser != null)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginDetails.EmailID, loginDetails.RememberMe);
                        Session["EmailID"] = LoginUser.EmailID;
                        Session["UserID"] = LoginUser.UserID;
                        return RedirectToAction("CalendarView", "Appt", new { CustomerUserid = Session["UserID"]});
                       // return RedirectToAction("Details/" + Session["UserID"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login data is incorrect!");
                    }

                }
            }
            return View(loginDetails);
        }
```

Please help me to achieve this .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Create partialview for login page instead and load it using jquery.

Comment: Thanks, Can you explain how to load using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller code should look something like this

```
public ActionResult YourControllerAction( int Userid )
{
  //Add your logic here
    return PartialView( "UserDetails", model );
}
```

Your partial view should look like this

```
@model Models.Login

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>login</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <div>      
        /*Your markup here*/
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your jQuery code should look something like this.

```
$('#loginlinkid').on('click', function(evt) {
    var $loginDiv = $('#PopUpDiv')
    $.get(urlOfYourAction, function(data) {
        $loginDiv.replaceWith(data);
    });
   //Add code to open popup here. eg..bootstrap modal dialog
});
```

Similar post here [Render a partial view inside a Jquery modal popup on top of a parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923305/render-a-partial-view-inside-a-jquery-modal-popup-on-top-of-a-parent-view)